# App crashes when accessing CLLocation

Tags: iphone, cllocation

I have a CLLocation that I set to the current location within the following function

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

currentLocation = newLocation;
}
```

When I try to access the current position in a later method the app crashes.

```
NSLog(@"current latitude is %f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);
NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
NSString *latitude =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
```

The current position is set in the first method. I can print it out, what is weird is that I have this currentLocation defined as a pointer in the header.

The app crashes and there is no stacktrace. The debugger just sends me to the retValue of my app.

I tried retaining the pointer as well as alloc before setting it to the newLocation, but nothing seems to work.

What am I missing :D

Comment: what if you use %f instead of %g? Or try making currentLocation a property, so you'll have `self.currentLocation` instead?

Comment: How is `currentLocation` declared in your .h file?

Comment: CLLocation *currentLocation;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *currentLocation;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not so sure about your code but I can suggest this

> I tried retaining the pointer as well as alloc before setting it to the newLocation, but nothing seems to work.

You need to retain newLocation pointer not the currentLocation before setting.

```
currentLocation = [newLocation retain];
```

or

```
self.currentLocation = newLocation;
```

Because your assignment `currentLocation = newLocation;` does not retain the pointer and newLocation is autorelease.

Answer (score 1):

> The app crashes and there is no
>   stacktrace. The debugger just sends me
>   to the retValue of my app.

Are you using Xcode 4?  A lot of people are having trouble with the new interface.  At the bottom of the stack trace window there's a slider, if it's set to be "coarse" it'll only show the app's main() block.

As indicated in the comments above, I reckon you should be saying `self.currentLocation` instead of `currentLocation`.  The difference is that when you just say currentLocation, you are only assigning a pointer.  To get all the "magic" functionality that you define in the header file (retain, et al), you need to use the `self.currentLocation` notation, OR, `[self setCurrentLocation:newLocation];`.  Functionally those are the same, it's a matter of style.